# post title not changing at post page

Tags: plugins, filters

I am using following code to change post title but it only change it in all posts list not at post page

```
add_filter('the_title', array($this,'change_title'), 10, 2);
    

public function change_title($title, $id)
{
    if (get_post_type($id) == "post") $title = 'Posted:&nbsp;' . $title;
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways to do it

```
if (get_post_type($id) == 'post' || get_post_type($id) == 'page')
```

If you use the same function more than once its better to create a variable that will hold that value, so like this

```
$type = get_post_type($id);

if ($type == 'post' || $type == 'page')
```

You could also do something like this

```
if (in_array(get_post_type($id), ['post', 'page']))
```

In this situation I would go with the `in_array` option, no variable created and very clean.

But you can use which ever option you like, the final result will be the same